# Icon next to multi-line button

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a button that has multi-line text and an icon next to it that is centered for both lines. Here's a screenshot for better understanding

[image: screenshot of desired result]

However, I'm not able to center the button. The icon is always next to the first line of the button, not to the second.

The code of my button

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: transparent;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  transition: background-color 100ms ease;
  outline: none !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #FBBC06;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #022753;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.btn:before {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: 'shopping_cart';
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<button class="btn">
    <span>von günstigstem Anbieter<br> in den Warenkorb legen</span>
</button>
```

As you can see the icon is only aligned to the first line in the button, but I want to have it vertically aligned to both of the lines.

I tried it without the span as well but the result was the same.

Comment: Thanks @MohammadUsman. I searched and searched but seems like I searched for the wrong term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`position: absolute`** to align the icon vertically center. I have changed some of your css. Please check below

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: transparent;
  padding: 6px 16px 6px 70px;
  transition: background-color 100ms ease;
  outline: none !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  line-height: 28px;
  background-color: #FBBC06;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #022753;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.btn:before {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  content: 'shopping_cart';
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50px;
  left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<button class="btn">
    <span>von günstigstem Anbieter<br> in den Warenkorb legen</span>
</button>
```

Comment: That was easier than I expected. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: inline-block` on `.btn>span` aligns both lines next to the icon. You can then use `vertical-align` to center them vertically.

```
.btn>span { display: inline-block }
```